# Can't find data using this xpath? in Python Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

https://www.volkswagen-vans.co.uk/en/offers-finance/offers/caddy-panel-van.html

```
       response.xpath('//div[@class="vw_m108_item_container vw_accordion_item_container"]//div[@class="inner"]/div[@class="td"]//text()')
```

Comment: I am scraping this site "https://www.volkswagen-vans.co.uk/en/offers-finance/offers/caddy-panel-van.html"

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49516102/edit) your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: We still need **your code**.

Comment: I have mentioned my code in my question, don't know what else code you are asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sort it out by changing my xpath.

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="vw_m108_item_container vw_accordion_item_container"][contains(@data-sectionname, "finance lease")]//div[@class="tr"]//text()')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) is not the problem but your (missing) code; in Chrome Dev Tools -> console, I get :

```
$x('//div[@class="vw_m108_item_container vw_accordion_item_container"]//div[@class="inner"]/div[@class="td"]//text()').length
```

#### Output :

```
84
```

When you post here on SO, like [@some-progammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9540923/some-progammer) said, always post your code.

Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't Need length actually, I need scrapped data of this site

Comment: Just a proof that the request works. If the count is 84, the request works. Shrugs

Comment: You are right **Giles** it should give data as well but not giving data, although all data is coming in the source code, it means there are no ajax requests running but still I am unable to get my required data.